# How to enable Mongodb Atlas data encryption at rest

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to enable data encryption at rest for mongodb Atlas.The documentation is ambiguous.Some places it says its enabled by default and other places it says it is optional and uses underneath AWS volume encryption.Can any help me understand whether Atlas provides data at rest encryption.If so how to enable it.Thank you

Comment: What are you asking? This maybe [Atlas REST API](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/api/)?

Comment: Hi Neil, In their security section they say, they provide "optionally encrypted storage volumes" .Please check the Strong-security part of the FAQ https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/faq . I don't understand what do they mean by "optionally encrypted storage volumes".Thanks

Comment: So you are asking about whether the "data storage" is encrypted or not? Call MongoDB support. "Optionally" in this context usually means you **pay for it** at a premium price. Sounds like you have a sales question, Talk to sales and get them to answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is documented at https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/secure-your-mongodb-database-on-the-aws-cloud

> Disk Encryption
>
> MongoDB Atlas clusters on AWS make use of the General Purpose SSD
>   (gp2) EBS volumes, which include support for AES-256 encryption.
>   MongoDB Atlas makes encrypting your data at rest simple by allowing
>   you to just point and click from the management GUI to encrypt your
>   persistent storage

[image]